# Powershell recursive remote registry export to csv

Tags: powershell, registry, export-to-csv, recursive-query

I am trying to export in CSV format an entire registry folder from remote computer but I have no result and I am not able to set the remote computer I am trying to query.

```
$RegPath=HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Google    
Get-ChildItem $RegPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -notypeinformation
```

Comment: use invoke command to do that against a remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

To get a registry item on a remote PC you accomplish this is two ways. First over WSMAN using `Invoke-Command`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ExampleComputer" -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\
} | Export-CSV -path $ExportFile -notypeinformation
```

Or you can use .Net methods over Remote Registry

```
$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', "ExampleComputer")
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Google")
$Value = $RegKey.GetValue("ExampleValue")
$SubKeys = $RegKey.GetSubKeyNames()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Get-ChildItem` accepts a remote PC name, you would need to use something like `Get-WmiObject` with registry class.

you're best bet is to use [psremoteregistry](http://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/)

Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry in an elevated window then use. You could use the native win32 registry class in .net but it's a bit more advanced.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could be an alternative solution, an idea how I can proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ScriptBlock=@'
$Table=@()
$RegKeys=Get-ChildItem -Path $RegPath -Recurse
$RegKeys=@($RegKeys)
for ($i=0; $i -lt $RegKeys.Count; $i++) {
  $RegKeys[$i].Property | ForEach-Object { $TableRow=New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{Key=$RegKeys[$i].Name;Value=$_;Data=$RegKeys[$i].GetValue($_)}; $Table+=$TableRow }
}
$Table
'@
$ScriptBlock=[System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create($ScriptBlock)
$Results=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
$Results | Select-Object -Property Key,Value,Data | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```